# Scraping with NodeJS on website containing javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, soundcloud

I'm using request to scrape web pages from someone's SoundCloud page. On load SoundCloud is checking wether javascript is enabled or not and then loads the track list.

When I'm scraping the page it just returns a sample html with an error about Javascript being disabled.

Is there a workaround for this?
Can I "capture" the requests made by the SoundCloud javascript to get the song list and do them myself in nodeJs?

Ps: This is a personal side project, weird solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be at home with [CasperJS FAQ](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html) and [home page](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html)